# Changing first word in matched variable lines

Tags: bash

I could not think of an appropriate title for this so excuse me if what I want does not match the title.

I have a config that has output of interface statistics from Cisco devices. My script then goes through and parses the lines of data and separates it so that it can export certain items to a CSV. The scripts works great for all others ports until it runs into ATM ports. The problem data that I am trying to parse looks like the following:

```
ATM0/0/0 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
ATM0/0/0.1 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
ATM0/0/0.2 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
```

My script to parse the information works as follows:

```
cfg=./config.text
inter=$(cat $cfg | grep "protocol is" | awk '{print $1}')

for i in $inter
do
if [[ $i == ATM0/*/0.* ]] ; then
cat $cfg | grep -A2 "$i" | sed -e 's/--//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' | paste -d " " - - - > tmp
    grep "$i" ./tmp | while read -r line ; do
            sts1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/,//g')
            sts2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $6}')
            sts3=$(echo $line | awk '{print $8}')
            sts4=$(echo $line | awk '{print $10}')
    echo "$hostname, $ip, $i, $sts1, $sts2, $sts3, $sts4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA" >> Details.csv
    done
elif [[ $i == ATM0/*/0 ]] ; then
           similar coding as above
   echo "$var, $var, $var" >> Details.csv
done
fi
done
```

The problem is that since the main ATM and sub ATM ports both start with ATM, my grep commands are not able to distinguish between the two. So it is picking up the next 4 lines after it matches "ATM0/*/0".

I have tried to use sed to try to change the sub ATM ports from ATM to a unique name so that it can get through the data processing. The code I used for that was the following:

```
if cat $cfg | grep "ATM0/[0-3]/0.[0-3]" ; then
sed -i 's/ATM/SUB_VAR/'
fi
```

Unfortunately this changed all ATM instances into SUB_VAR. I am unsure how to approach this issue and looking for guidance on how to accomplish this.

**UPDATE:**
Each IF statement is supposed to match the first pattern and then grab a set amount of lines after that pattern and put it in a tmp file. From there it formats it so for each matched pattern, gets put into one line, like the following:

```
 ATM0/0/0.1 is up, protocol is up line 1 line 2
 ATM0/0/0.2 is up, protocol is up line 1 line 2
 ATM0/1/0.1 is up, protocol is up line 1 line 2
 ATM0/1/0.2 is up, protocol is up line 1 line 2
```

From here I am able to use awk to parse the information I want. The problem is that the pattern matching for the ATM ports is grabbing both the ATM and ATM sub ports. From there the wrong output looks like this to the tmp file:

```
ATM0/1/0 is up, protocol is up line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4
ATM0/1/0.1 is up, protocol is up line 1 line 2 ATM0/1/0.2 is up, protocol is up line 1
line 2 FastEthernet0/1 is up, protocol is up line 1
```

As you can see, it works fine for the sub ports but as you can see for the regular ports, its grabbing things it shouldn't be and I am sure its because of the pattern I am using for my IF statements.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Most likely your complete script can be replaced with one `awk` script but reverse engineering the required output is a challenge.  You can get more help if you post a representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: @JamesBrown Updated original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
sed -r "s/ATM0(\/[0-3]+\/0[^.].*)/atm0\1/" atm.log 

atm0/0/0 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
ATM0/0/0.1 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
ATM0/0/0.2 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
```

The dot in square brackets matches the literal dot. The caret before negates it.

With -i you would change the file in place.

```
sed -r -i "s/ATM0(\/[0-3]+\/0[^.].*)/atm0\1/" atm.log
```

Change the opposite way:

```
sed -r "s/ATM0(\/[0-3]+\/0[.].*)/atm0\1/" atm.log 

ATM0/0/0 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
atm0/0/0.1 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
atm0/0/0.2 is up, protocol is up
line 1
line 2
```

I guess atm in lowercase might not get in conflict with other names, but be a good indication/documentation, what the original entry was.

Comment: This worked exactly that I was hoping for! Thank you again!